# Placing Flash content above an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash

I need to display Flash content, and I have an image that is "encasing" the Flash content, the image is a PNG with the center transparent.

In Windows 7 and FF and IE it works ok, in Chrome however the Flash content is non-interactive, like if it was rendering behind the image.

In Windows 8 only seems to work in FF, in IE is broken too.

Any ideas how to go around this?. Is there some kind of layer of depth I can set somewhere?.

Comment: I remember that this issue is related to the `wmode` of the swf, but could you put an example of your code or a link to an online page ?

Comment: I'm using wmode="direct" because I'm using Starling (stage3D).